# Peace lily grows another peace lily

Tags: plant-health

[image]

What does it mean when my peace lily grow something like new peace lily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the plant has enough water, light and soil nutrients to grow wider.
This is a good thing and not a cause for concern.

Comment: I saw on instagram. It’s a sign that the plant is stressed. And I thought it trying to escape. By growing new one?

Comment: @Dini as long as it's growing new leaves and getting bigger the plant is fine